# What JQuery selector excludes items with a parent that matches a given selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have

```
var $set = $('.foo,.bar').filter(
    function() {return $(this).parents('.baz').length < 1;});
```

as a way to select all the elements whose classes are either `foo` or `bar` and who do not descend from an element whose class is `baz`.  Is there a selector that will accomplish the same thing without the need for a filtering lambda?

```
<div class='foo'/><!--match this-->
<div class='bar'/><!--match this-->
<div class='baz'>
    <div class='foo'/> <!--don't match this-->
</div>
```

Comment: you can use the `closest` method rather than `parents` to make it faster. `closest` stops looking once it finds a matching element while `parents` travels up the DOM tree to the document's root element to find matching elements.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The truth of the matter is that jQuery simply does not have a particularly elegant way to do what you want. While chaos' answer does work, you have to wonder whether the complicated selector (that would be about as slow as a selector can be in a complicated webpage) is worth it over the more verbose but faster filter function you have. This is not really that big of a deal, I am just personally weary of particularly long, convoluted selectors when I can avoid it.

A different option is to create your own selector, since jQuery is awesome:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].parents = function(a,i,m){
    return jQuery(a).parents(m[3]).length < 1;
};

$('.foo,.bar').filter(':parents(.baz)');
```

The `expr` map is part of the Sizzle selector engine and documentation can be found here: [Sizzle Custom Pseudo-Selectors](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki#-pseudo-selectors-pseudos)

Comment: accepting because it's more complete than chaos' - where do I find the documentation on the API for the expr array?

Comment: There's not really any, as far as I know.

Comment: That is tidy, though I think I might change the expression name to noparents, as that describes what it's doing a little better.

Comment: The link to that JSBin doesn't match the answer. It's been a while, so the URL must have been recycled.

Comment: I added a reference to the documentation for `expr` on this answer.

Answer (score 31):

```
$('.foo:not(.baz .foo),.bar:not(.baz .bar)')
```

Answer (score 18):

I couldn't get this to work:

```
$(".children:not(#parent .children)");
```

But I can get this to work:

```
$(".children").not($("#parent .children"));
```

Note: Not sure if this has something to do with the jQuery version I'm using 1.2.6

Comment: Using `$().not()` is the simplest solution. And is well [documented](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to do just what's been asked.

Answer (score 5):

try this one:

```
$('div').filter(function () {
  return ($(this).parent().not('.baz'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector **chaos** gives should work:

```
$('.foo:not(.baz .foo),.bar:not(.baz .bar)')
```

Just wanted to give you a tip about an extension to [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) called [FireFinder](http://robertnyman.com/firefinder/) that you can use to test your css/jquery selectors.

From the website: *Firefinder is an extension to Firebug (in Firefox) and offers the functionality to, in a quick way, find HTML elements matching chosen CSS selector(s) or XPath expression. It allows you to instantly test your CSS selectors in the page while seeing the content at the same time, and matching elements will be highlighted.*

Answer (score 1):

`var $li = jQuery('li', this).not('.dropdown-menu > li');`

I'm using Roots theme and they change the dropdowns from 'sub-menu' to '.dropdown-menu'

Answer (score 0):

Add a :not('.baz') to your top level selector.