# jQuery lavaLamp, misbehaving with child <ul>'s

Tags: jquery, nested, html-lists, lavalamp

I've been playing around with http://nixboxdesigns.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/ for a navigation menu on a new site I'm building and it works great with minimal fuss, I then started wondering if I could add some sub navigation options to the menu and set about building that in. The trouble I'm having is making the lavaLamp plugin ignore nested/child ul/li's.

You can see a live example of the issue here: http://www.weleasewodewick.com/redesign2 - hover over the 'Blog' li then over the submenu that pops in.

I won't post the full source for the plugins as it's pretty lengthy but you should be able to view them directly here:

**lavaLamp jQuery Plugin**

http://www.weleasewodewick.com/redesign2/includes/jquery.lavalamp.js

**Menu Markup**

```
<nav> 
 <article> 
  <ul> 
   <li><a href="#Home" alt="#">Root</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#About" alt="#">Who?</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#Projects" alt="#">Projects</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#Resume" alt="#">Blog</a> 
     <ul class='children'> 
      <li class="page_item page-item-18"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=18" title="History">History</a></li> 
      <li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=13" title="Our Company">Our Company</a></li> 
      <li class="page_item page-item-15"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=15" title="Our Staff">Our Staff</a></li> 
     </ul> 
</li> 
    <li><a href="#Resume" alt="#">Contact</a></li> 
   </ul> 
  </article> 
 </nav>
```

**lavaLamp Activation**

```
$(function() { $('nav>article>ul').lavaLamp(); });
```

Would really appreciate your input on this issue :)

** Purpose **
The final resting place of this mockup is a WordPress template, so the nested structure of the menu mostly needs to remain the same.

Much appreciated
Foxed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

huh, finally I got it work :)
here's the **Demo** : **http://jsbin.com/uyali3**

It is difficult to achieve this task using `<ul>` as child node, so I changed  it to `<div>`

go check out the code **yourself** =)

**NOTE** : Next time when you post a question please be sure, to provide the proper code/HTML. I took me around `45 min`  to understand your entire code. At last I found a fix to your problem =)

**Code** :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> cssFix </title>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <style type="text/css">

        body { background : #2f2f2f; }

         ul  li {
        display:inline;
        float:left;
        list-style-type:none;
        margin-right:10px;
        position:relative;
        z-index:5;
        }
         ul  li.backLava {
        -moz-border-radius :6px;
        background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #009912;
        }
         ul  li a {
        color:#B9B9B9;
        display:block;
        font: bold 14px Arial;
        padding:17px 10px 6px;
        position:relative;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-shadow:0 1px 0 #38302F;
        }
         ul  li  a:hover {
        color:#ff0;
        font-size:14px;

        }
        ul  li a:active {
        color:#FFFFFF;
        }
        .children {
        background-color:#333333;
        left:-999em;
        list-style:none outside none;
        min-width:100px;
        position:absolute;
        }

        li:hover .children {
        -moz-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;
        background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        left:auto;
        margin:0;
        padding:10px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul style="position: relative;" class="ulclass">
            <li class="selectedLava"><a alt="#" href="#Home">Root</a></li>
            <li><a alt="#" href="#About">Who?</a></li>
            <li><a alt="#" href="#Projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li>
                <a alt="#" href="#Resume">Blog</a>
                <div class="children"> 
                    <span><a href="#">History</a></span> 
                    <span><a href="#">Our Company</a></span> 
                    <span><a href="#">Our Staff</a></span> 
                </div> 
            </li>
            <li><a alt="#" href="#Resume">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.weleasewodewick.com/redesign2/includes/jquery.lavalamp.js" ></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function() {
            $('ul').lavaLamp();
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I had hoped seeing the full source code would have made it simpler to understand. I guess not. I'll update the question with specific now. Whilst your solution is great and it works I'm really looking for it to operate in the structure provided - namely because this design is destined for Wordpress which uses nested ul's in its page navigation creation.

Comment: Changed my mind ... answer accepted. I'll just hack /includes/post-template.php on my WordPress install. Not best practice but I don't plan on distributing the theme so :)

Comment: It's not a good Idea to change the entire template :) I believe this can be done using `ul` but this requires some effort =) Re-Ask your querstion, I'm sure someone will answer you in a right way!! Please don't change the template.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question too, but I didn't want to modify wordpress templates:

Firstly I thought about adding the class "noLava" to every `<li>` with depth > 1, so I tried to expand the Walker class with a custom one - with no success.

Then I started to modify the lavalamp jquery plugin, and after having tried all day long I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965816/what-jquery-selector-excludes-items-with-a-parent-that-matches-a-given-selector/965962#965962), so I modified it as below, and it works like a charm :)

```
{find `var $li = jQuery('li[class!=noLava]', this);` and replace with:}

    //var $li = jQuery('li[class!=noLava]', this); //default one

    //by Paolo Bergantino, via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965816/what-jquery-selector-excludes-items-with-a-parent-that-matches-a-given-selector/965962#965962
    jQuery.expr[':'].parents = function(a,i,m){
        return jQuery(a).parents(m[3]).length < 1;
    }; 

    var $li = jQuery('li', this).filter(':parents(.children, .sub-menu)'); //for worpress :) by lelebart
```

Maybe the best solution is to preserve the original behavior and add this one.

Edit: [online demo]

Answer (score 0):

I forked the LavaLamp plugin, and added a "hoverTarget" option.
It uses an element inside the "target" element for the hover detection.
(default: "a")

This fixes the issues with child lists.

get it here: [GitHub](https://github.com/AvanOsch/jQuery-LavaLamp)