# Can you filter an existing jquery object by context?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some elements cached in a jquery object. I now want to filter them by context. Can I do this or do I need to create another jquery object with my selector while also using the second context param?

Here's an example:

```
var cached = $('.elements');
```

later I want to filter this array by context without creating another selector. If I was to just create another selector to do what I want it would look like this:

```
//in event listener
var parent = $(this).closest('.parent');
$('.elements', parent).removeClass('class');
```

Comment: "Can I do this" I would say yes, but your question is not clear. Please provide an example

Comment: can you paste you code here?

Comment: This may be of interest -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965816/what-jquery-selector-excludes-items-with-a-parent-that-matches-a-given-selector

Comment: The thread suggested by pebbl was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your request, if I don't get wrong, you can use `.not` (http://api.jquery.com/not/)

http://jsfiddle.net/kcy3f/

```
<span class="a">a1</span>
<span class="a">a2</span>
<span class="b">b3</span>
<span class="b">b4</span>

<script>
var all = $('span');
all.css("background", "#F99");
all = all.not(".a"); // remove class 'a' element
all.css("background", "#9F9");
</script>
```