# How to select element that isn't a child of specific element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can I select only the `span`s that do NOT have `div.option` as a parent?

```
<div class="option">
    <span>Content goes here</span>
</div>
<span>Content goes here</span>
<span>Content goes here</span>
<div class="option">
    <span>Content goes here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Quite a good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965816/what-jquery-selector-excludes-items-with-a-parent-that-matches-a-given-selector

Comment: Use the direct parent of this block, eg `.container > span`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select all `span` and using [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) exclude spans that is child of `.option`

```js
$("span:not(div.option > span)").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option">
    <span>Content goes here</span>
</div>
<span>Content goes here</span>
<span>Content goes here</span>
<div class="option">
    <span>Content goes here</span>
</div>
```